# A for loop with different input values

Tags: javascript

I Need to write a for loop like below mention way  ie:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var startday=5
var endday=1

 for(var k=startday;k>endday;k++){

   }
```

and my output would be like : 5,6,7,1

I have tried the code but the values are coming like 5,6,7,8,9.......

Comment: If you want your loop to stop, you'd need to use something like `for (k=startDay;k > endDay; k--)` otherwise it loops forever.

Comment: output `((k - 1) % 7) + 1`

Comment: @pandu what is your criteria... you need elements starting from your startdate till at the end of your array and the last element should be your end day right?

Comment: var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var startday=5 var endday=1 then the for loop out put is 5,6,7,1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is to iterate over an array with variable start and end.

1. Get the start index form the `array`
2. Get the end index from the `array`
3. Adjust the end if it is smaller than start, add in this case `array.length`
4. Iterate over the new start and end indices
5. Adjust the index, because it can runs outside the `array.length` with the remainder operator.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    startday = 5,
    endday = 1,
    k,
    start = array.indexOf(startday),
    end = array.indexOf(endday);

if (end < start) {
    end += array.length;
}
for (var k = start; k <= end; k++ ){
    document.write(array[k % array.length] + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--k` as third parameter of `for` (it causes `k` variable to be decremented)

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var startday=5;
var endday=1
for (var k=startday; k >= endday; --k)
{
}
```

Comment: requested output, 5,6,7,1 is not in descending order

Answer (score 0):

inside your loop, print this 'array[k]' , and 'if(k > array.length){ print 1 and break}'

Comment: answers a specific case only, what if endday is 2

Comment: make a modification print endday instead of 1.

Comment: so it would be like this? 'print endday and break' instead of print 1

Comment: and there is another issue.. if the array is [4,5,6,7,8,9] and start day is 5 the array[5] will give you 8

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `for` loop?
How about this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var startday = 5;
var endday = 1;
var k = startday;
while (k > endday){
    // print array[k-1]

    if (k == array.length){
        k = 1;
    } else {
        k++;
    }
}
while (k <= endday){
    // print array[k-1]

    k++;
}
```

I'm assuming startday and endday refer to an array index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77];

var startday=55;
var endday=11;

var lastEl = array[array.length-1];
var index_startday =  $.inArray( startday, array );

 for(var count=index_startday; count <= array.length;count++){
    alert(array[count]);
    if(array[count] == endday){
        break;
    }
    if(array[count] == lastEl){
      count = -1;
      continue;
    }
   }
</script>
```